# AccuRev Plug-in integration with VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, accurev

I am trying use Accrev plugin for visual studio 2010. I am not sure how do i get this working on VS 2010 for projects which are already existing in Accrev. I have followed few steps mentioned in the release notes.

Release notes for the plug in contains the instructions for adding a new solution from VS to Accrev or creating a new one.

After installation i am getting Accurev option in File. But solution does not show bindings with  to Accrev. All options in File ->Accurev are disabled.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Shetty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with, I find it almost impossible to use only the plugin and not AccuRev itself. Therefore I recommend using both. Then you can also manage your workspace(s) in AccuRev and populate a solution to your local folder.

Then you open the solution in Visual Studio. Make sure you are logged in to AccuRev from Visual Studio. If not, you should have the File > AccuRev > Login option. After you are logged in VS 'knows' the binding and will refresh the bindings.

I stumbled upon another issue that the AccuRev option under File wasn't showing up. This happens when another Source Control Management system is set up under Tools > Options > Source Control. Make sure that AccuBridge is selected here.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am using both the accrev and plugin. I have selected the correct pluging option under Tools->options->Source Control. I have downloaded an existing solution from Accrev to my local workspace. Then when i opened the solution from VS2010 i was hopng that my my solution would show binding with Accurev. But it was not. I am getting Accurev option under file, but it has only CreateWorkspace,Login and Synchrinise Options. I could loging from thr but other options in the Accrev menu never gets enabled.

Comment: It sounds like you need to Login to the AccuRev server first (with the File > AccuRev > Login option). If that succeeds, it should bind automatically.

Comment: If logging in doesn't work then it's possible that your login credentials for AccuRev are different from your Windows credentials. In that case you need to add an Environment Variable in Windows. To do this in Win7 open the Properties from Computer > Click Advanced System Settings > Goto Advanced tab > click Environment Variables at the bottom. Here you have to add a new User Variable named ACCUREV_PRINCIPAL and give it your AccuRev Username as value. Not quite sure, but I think you have to log in to Windows again before this variable will be recognised.

Comment: I have checkd the loging. Login is successful. But i do not see any bindings.

Answer (score 2):

It has been my experience that sometimes hitting Accurev Refresh helps in situations like this. Hope it helps.